# What happens if I accidentally clicked on Enable connected campaigns and engagement history?

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, account, pardot, sales

I accidentally clicked on the checkbox under connector settings > campaign tab, and then unticked it in account engagement. For context, this is a new org and it's connector has not been unpaused. I noticed that website tracking and email plugin campaigns are now connected. What are the implications of my actions? Is this serious considering this is a production org?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.